# Grouping similar values into new select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks something like this...

```
supplier_name  status       count 
supplier_a     Unavailable  1
supplier_a     Refunded     5
supplier_a     Shipped      10
supplier_z     Refunded     2
supplier_z     Shipped      4
```

I know exactly what columns I want and I would like to use the values from the first table to return values structured like the following...

```
supplier_name   unavailable   refunded   shipped
supplier_a      1             5          10
supplier_z      0             2          4
```

(note: in cases where there is no value for a specific column it should be set to 0)

Would this be possible to achieve in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT Supplier_Name, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Unavailable' THEN Count ELSE 0 END) as Unavailable,
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Refunded' THEN Count ELSE 0 END) as refunded,
  MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Shipped' THEN Count ELSE 0 END) as shipped
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Supplier_Name
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46ed6/2).

Good luck.

Comment: @mk_89 -- glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   supplier_name,
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN status = 'unavailable' THEN  `count` END, 0)) unavailable,
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN status = 'refunded' THEN  `count` END, 0)) refunded,
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN status = 'shipped' THEN  `count` END, 0)) shipped
FROM tbl
GROUP BY supplier_name
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b5f1/3)**

Comment: I have no doubt that this works but they first answer worked fine

Comment: @mk_89 Does you have more than one row with the current status for the same supplier?